# MySQL sum negative and sum of positive values without sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as follows:

```
tbl_answers : id, (FK)authorID ...

tbl_answer_votes : id, (FK)voterID, (FK)answerID, vote (sInt, only ever -1 or 1)
```

`tbl_answers` has a one to many relationship with `tbl_answer_votes` and a vote can be either negative 1 or positive 1.

I need to join `tbl_answer_votes` on to `tbl_answers` but produce the sum of all negative votes for that answer and the sum of all positive votes for the answer as two separate columns.

I can do this by sub-querying but as it will be a small part of a larger query and after reading the pitfalls on sub-queries I would like to try and produce those two negative and positive sums from the votes table as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` and a `JOIN` to accomplish this:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  SUM(CASE v.vote when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as UpVotes,
  SUM(CASE v.vote when -1 then 1 else 0 end) as DownVotes
FROM 
  tbl_answers a
INNER JOIN 
  tbl_answer_votes v
ON 
  v.id = a.id
GROUP BY 
  a.id
```

This returns the `ID` from `tbl_answers` and the two columns with the total votes of either value from `tbl_answer_votes`. You didn't specify which (if any) other columns you'd want from either table, so you may have to adjust the column list in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` portions to add additional columns.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i dont have time. but here you might have to twick it little bit.

```
 select a.id, SUM(CASE WHEN v.vote = 1 Then 1 ELSE 0 END ), SUM(CASE WHEN (v.vote = -1) then 1 ELSE 0 end)
from tbl_answers a
inner join tbl_answer_votes v
    On a.id = v.asnwerId
where a.id = 123
group by a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a query that returns the sum of the votes, and the count of the votes for each answer.

Since

```
sum of votes = positive votes - negative votes
count of votes = positive votes + negative votes
```

you have

```
positive votes = (count+sum)/2
negative votes = (count-sum)/2
```

so just add those expressions to your query. Something like

```
SELECT answerID, (COUNT(*)+SUM(vote))/2 as upvotes,
                 (COUNT(*)-SUM(vote))/2 as downvotes
FROM tbl_answer_votes
GROUP BY answerID
```

and then you should be OK for the join part.